# error in .local (obj, ) cannat derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix in kriging interpolation

Tags: r

I tried to use the kriging interpolation on map using R. However, I got stuck in the first step. I used this to import the data into R.

```
td<read.table(pipe("pbpaste"),header=TRUE,sep="\t",dec=".",na.strings="NA",stringsAsFactors=F)
```

And I need to transform my data to a `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` (provided by the `sp` package):

```
gridded(td) = c("x","y")
```

And this returns an error:

> error in .local(obj, ...) : cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix

Are that anything wrong with my dataset, how can I deal with it?

Comment: Are you really importing data this way? `td<read.table`?

Comment: The `x` and `y` columns are not `numeric` (they are probably `factor`s). See `str(td)` to check whether you imported your data correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I used str(td) and found that " x : Factor w/ ". However, the format of these data is numeric. I have no idea why it was like this in R.

Comment: I found the error, Thank you all. And happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My X,Y coordinates were floats. I changed them into integers and then it worked. Try that !!

Comment: This is a terrible suggestion. You will generally have inaccurate coordinates this way.